# Add custom props to GetServerSidePropsContext in NextJS

Tags: typescript, redux, next.js

I have this HOC set up that I used for every page. So far, this seems working fine. I'm using next-redux-wrapper

**withAuth.tx**

```
export function withAuthRedux(gssp: CustomGetServerSidePropsContext): CustomGetServerSidePropsContext {
  return wrapper.getServerSideProps(store => async (ctx: Custom) => {
    const auth = await checkUser(ctx);
    if (!auth) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: routes.auth.login,
          statusCode: 302,
        },
      };
    }
    await store.dispatch(setAuthUser(auth.attributes));
    return await gssp({ ...ctx, params: { ...ctx.params, currentUser: auth.attributes } });
  });
}
```

But my problem is that, I wanted to access the `store` as well into my page under getServerSideProps like so

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = withAuthRedux(async ({ locale, params, store <-- this store}) => {
  const auth = params?.currentUser as any; // TODO
  
  store.dispatch(setRole(1)); // works but have typing error
  
  return {
    props: {
      ...
    },
  };
});
```

I tried passing the store in the gssp. It works, I have the function but I got typing error says it doesn't exists in GetServerSidePropsContext. How can I modify GetServerSidePropsContext to add additional parameter in the context?

```
interface CustomGetServerSidePropsContext extends GetServerSideProps {
  store?: AppStore
}

interface Custom extends GetServerSidePropsContext<any, any> {
  store?: AppStore;
}
```

One solution that seems working is I have to wrap my wrapped function like so

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(store =>
  withAuthRedux(async ({ locale, params }) => {
    const auth = params?.currentUser as any; // TODO


    return {
      props: {
        ...
      },
    };
  }),
);
```

Just to access the `store` but not sure if its good or not